# Delegate for Generic Property.GetSetMethod

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am trying to create a delegate for setting a property value of a generic, but I am getting an error: `Error binding to target method` when I try to execute the following code:

```
Action<T, object> setValue = (Action<T, object>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<T, object>), null, property.GetSetMethod());
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is your property a static property?  If not, then you can't pass null.

Comment: No it's not, sorry I missed that piece, but even when I pass in an instance of the class it does not work correctly, I still get the same exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you're just trying to create a delegate of the wrong type.  The set method of a property only takes one argument, the value you're going to set.  Also  since its an instance method, you must pass the target object you want it to be bound to in the CreateDelegate call.

Example:

```
  var setValue = (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<T> ), target, property.GetSetMethod() );
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends. In my answer I assume two things:

1. Your type "T" is the type of your class (which I will now denote as TClass)
2. The type "object" is the type of your property (which I will now denote as TProperty)

Because your property is a non-static, there are two possibilies:

1. An "normal" delegate with the target (instance) attached.
2. An "open" delegate with in which a target is required as the first input parameter of the delegate.

A function to create such "normal" delegate is created as follows:

```
static public Action<TClass, TProperty> CreateSetPropertyDelegate<TClass, TProperty>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return (Action<TClass, TProperty>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TClass, TProperty>), propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());
}
```

And in use (assuming the property type is of type int):

```
Action<int> setter = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty").CreateSetPropertyDelegate<MyClass, int>(myInsance);
setter(myPropertyValue);
```

A function to create an open delegate:

```
static public Action<TClass, TProperty> CreateSetPropertyDelegate<TClass, TProperty>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return (Action<TClass, TProperty>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TClass, TProperty>), propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());
}
```

And in use:

```
Action<MyClass, int> setter = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyProperty").CreateSetPropertyDelegate<MyClass, int>();
setter(myInsance, myPropertyValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
Action<T, object> setValue = (t, o) => property.GetSetMethod().Invoke(t, new object[] { o });
```

or

```
Action<T, object> setValue = (t, o) => property.SetValue(t, o, null);
```

**EDIT**

To illustrate the assumed poorer performance of this answer compared to the accepted answer, assume this method:

```
void SetAnObjectPropertyOnALotOfObjects<T>(IEnumerable<T> objs)
{
    //Create a delegate and assign a reference to that delegate to the setValue variable
    Action<T, object> setValue = GetSetter();

    foreach (var o in objs)
    {
        //invoke the delegate referred to by the setValue variable (that is, "invoke its referent"
        setValue.Invoke(o, new object());
    }
}
```

MerickOWA's answer uses reflection in the `GetSetter` method, so we assume that the `GetSetter` method takes more time to execute, in his approach.  This answer uses reflection each time we call `setValue.Invoke`, so we assume that takes more time to execute in this answer.  If we assume the number of items in the sequence is large, MerickOWA's answer should require less time to execute.

For example, let's say that MerickOWA's GetSetter method takes X milliseconds more than mine to execute, while my setValue delegate takes Y milliseconds more than his.  If there are N items in the sequence, then my solution should be slower than his by (N * Y - X) milliseconds.

Comment: This uses the PropertyInfo to set the value every time, this is much slower than what CreateDelegate would return

Comment: Can you tell me why this method would be slower? In my tests, lambda performed in half the time of create delegate.

Comment: @nawfal because with this technique, `setValue` is a reference to a delegate that uses reflection to get another delegate with which it sets the property value.  Every time you invoke the referent of `setValue`, you're using the reflection API.  The method in the accepted answer uses reflection to create a delegate that sets the property directly, so you're using the reflection API once, when you assign `setValue`; invocations of `setValue` do not use reflection.

Comment: @phoog but why do I get improved performance with your answer and not MerickOWA's? Or should I make it a separate question?

Comment: @nawfal What performance are you measuring, specifically?  The performance of assigning a value to `setValue`, or the performance of invoking `setValue`?

Comment: @phoog performance of assigning value using `SetValue` by invoking the returned action delegate. I am not sure what's the difference you mean by both exactly. I tried setting values to a property in a loop by invoking the action delegate returned by your method and accepted answer's method. Yours perform doubly fast. Any idea? I will be glad to make it a question if you want more details.

Comment: @nawfal of course that's quicker then because assigning `setValue` in my answer requires a single delegate creation, while MerickOWA's answer requires a delegate creation and a call to GetSetMethod (which also creates a delegate).  The reason my answer is said to perform more poorly is because we are assuming that we will set the `setValue` variable once, and then invoke its referent many times.  The delegate invocation in MerickOWA's answer should be much quicker than in mine.

Comment: @nawfal If you would like to post more detail of your analysis in a new question, I would be happy to read it.  If you do so, please add a link here in a new comment, so I can be sure not to miss it.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I do not know what you mean by `then invoke its referent many times`. Why are you invoking it? To set the property value right? How is it different? May be I'm not competent enough to understand you, but can you guide me to a relevant example (of the one you're talking about where your method is slower) from msdn, or so, or at least good keywords so that I can google?

Comment: @phoog ok I will do, not now, but in less than a day. Thanks.

Comment: @nawfal I have added a performance discussion to my answer, in part to clarify the difference between "assigning the setValue variable" and "invoking its referent".

Comment: @phoog *This answer uses reflection each time we call setValue.Invoke*, ok I get it. The delegate to `SetValue` method is called each time. But isn't it the same as the accepted answer? Isn't he too returning a delegate to `SetValue` method? If I'm calling it in a loop, wouldnt the action delegate actually delegate the call to `GetSetMethod` its pointing to? In other words, why is your approach alone using reflection multiple times? Sorry for troubling, may be I should make it another question. I will be glad to do so if you're already bored :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27440/discussion-between-phoog-and-nawfal)

Comment: @phoog I understand the difference now. When I re-read your statement, "*setValue is a reference to a delegate that uses **reflection** to get another delegate with which it sets the property value. The method in the accepted answer uses reflection to create a delegate that **sets the property directly***" (in other words `GetSetMethod` is the method that points to the very getter - so more like a direct handle.. That's why I did not make it another question. Your help was great and I am grateful.. Hope I got it right..