# Is there a way to create a delegate to get and set values for a FieldInfo?

Tags: c#, delegates, expression-trees, setvalue, fieldinfo

For properties there are `GetGetMethod` and `GetSetMethod` so that I can do:

```
Getter = (Func<S, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<S, T>), 
                                             propertyInfo.GetGetMethod());
```

and

```
Setter = (Action<S, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<S, T>), 
                                               propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());
```

But how do I go about `FieldInfo`s?

I am not looking for delegates to `GetValue` and `SetValue` (which means I will be invoking reflection each time)

```
Getter = s => (T)fieldInfo.GetValue(s);
Setter = (s, t) => (T)fieldInfo.SetValue(s, t);
```

but if there is a `CreateDelegate` approach here? **I mean [since assignments return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value), can I treat assignments like a method?** If so is there a `MethodInfo` handle for it? In other words **how do I pass the right `MethodInfo` of setting and getting a value from a member field to `CreateDelegate` method so that I get a delegate back with which I can read and write to fields directly?**

```
Getter = (Func<S, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<S, T>), fieldInfo.??);
Setter = (Action<S, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<S, T>), fieldInfo.??);
```

*I can build expression and compile it, but I am looking for something simpler. In the end I don't mind going the expression route if there is no answer for the asked question*, as shown below:

```
var instExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S));
var fieldExp = Expression.Field(instExp, fieldInfo);
Getter = Expression.Lambda<Func<S, T>>(fieldExp, instExp).Compile();
if (!fieldInfo.IsInitOnly)
{
    var valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<S, T>>(Expression.Assign(fieldExp, valueExp), instExp, valueExp).Compile();
}
```

Or am I after the nonexistent (since I have nowhere seen something like that yet) ?

Comment: Is there some reason why you need to call `Delegate.CreateDelegate`? You already have a delegate with `getter`. Simply calling `getter(myInstanceOfT)` will invoke the `fieldInfo.GetValue` method and return you the value.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes performance is the key. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087611/delegate-for-generic-property-getsetmethod

Comment: This `Func<S, T> getter = s => (T)fieldInfo.GetValue(s);` all you can do, because field doesn't have the setter\getter method as it is in a property. If performance is the key I recommend to use the Expression.

Comment: @vvs0205 I know I will have to eventually use expression if I can't pass a methodinfo for setting and getting values to a field. Just seeing if it can be simulated.

Comment: Do you also want the delegate to work for readonly fields and private fields?

Comment: @MartinMulder readonly fields should only be readable. For private fields, yes (but I will use only in the *private* context - I mean inside the class itself). Basically I will respect the protection/privacy/visibility

Comment: @newfal: Take a look at my answer. You can modify it anyway you want to prefect readonly fields to stay readonly or you can forcibly overwrite them. Having these two little functions saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @MartinMulder I have already looked at your answer since it was posted. And as I said, it's only something I already posted in my question.

Comment: @newfal: True... you already suggested in this direction. But you asked for something as simple as: '(Func<S, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<S, T>), fieldInfo.?);' Such functions do not exists! I just suggested to create such a 'simple' function yourself. This way you prevent having Expressions everywhere in code and you can just call that simple function, exactly what you asked for. Now if the BODY of that function can be simpler, the anwer is simple: NO! (having the opion that IL is not simpler). Perhapse I misunderstand your question: Do you want a simpler call to or a simpler body?

Comment: @MartinMulder Honestly I was after a `get-set` method pair for fieldinfo (similar to properties) and not at all after a function that is named `CreateDelegate` but internally goes the expression route. That was not the purport of the question. If you took it so, I'm sorry. I accept I may not have worded the question as clearly as you would have wanted. I did not ask a question not knowing how to refactor a method and give it a name. Certainly not to open a bounty for it.

Comment: @Newfal: Well... in that case the answer is simple: No, there are no existing (fast) Get/Set-methods for a field, only the (slow) GetValue/SetValue of FieldInfo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Field access isn't performed via a method (like getters and setters)--it's performed with an IL instruction--so there's nothing you can *assign* to a delegate.  you'll have to use the expression route to create a "block" of code (effectively IL) that can be assigned to a delegate.

Comment: You're right I think. And there is nothing *reflection-ish* about it I believe, since assigning and reading via compiled expression were blazingly fast..

Comment: Yes, a compiled expression should b e just as fast as if you wrote you own method to access the field and compiled it normally.

Comment: Peter, I had once benchmarked compiled expression vs createdelegate for properties in getting and setting and createdelegate was the clear winner, hence this question

Comment: @nawfal Yes, but you need a method to use CreateDelegate--without that you have to create your own at compile-time, or at runtime (with compiled expressions or codegen--I don't think a compiled expression would be any faster than codegen).

Comment: I think that sums up as an answer, but I will wait for other answers as well before awarding bounty. I was waiting for a definitive take on it from the community.

Answer (score 32):

As Peter Ritchie suggested, you can compile your own code at runtime. The method will be compiled as soon as you invoke the delegate for the first time. So the first call will be slow, but any subsequent call will be as fast as you can get in .NET without unmanaged pointers/unions. Except for the first call, the delegate is around 500 times faster than FieldInfo directly.

```
class DemoProgram
{
    class Target
    {
        private int value;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FieldInfo valueField = typeof(Target).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.Instance).First();
        var getValue = CreateGetter<Target, int>(valueField);
        var setValue = CreateSetter<Target, int>(valueField);

        Target target = new Target();

        setValue(target, 42);
        Console.WriteLine(getValue(target));
    }

    static Func<S, T> CreateGetter<S, T>(FieldInfo field)
    {
        string methodName = field.ReflectedType.FullName + ".get_" + field.Name;
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, typeof(T), new Type[1] { typeof(S) }, true);
        ILGenerator gen = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        if (field.IsStatic)
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, field);
        }
        else
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
        }
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Func<S, T>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<S, T>));
    }

    static Action<S, T> CreateSetter<S,T>(FieldInfo field)
    {
        string methodName = field.ReflectedType.FullName+".set_"+field.Name;
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, null, new Type[2]{typeof(S),typeof(T)},true);
        ILGenerator gen = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        if (field.IsStatic)
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, field);
        }
        else
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        }
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<S, T>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<S, T>));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that structs are passed by value. That means an `Action<S, T>` can not be used to change members of a struct if it is passed by value as the first argument.

Comment: Its been a 50-50 between yours and Ritchie's answer. In the end I decided to choose his answer as correct since it gave the correct answer to the question; awarded you the bounty for the effort.

Comment: When the field is static (there's no 'this' pointer) why are you using Ldarg_1 instead of Ldarg_0?

Comment: Because the delegate is always (S obj, T value), even when the field is static. The user will pass null or something as the first argument.

Comment: To avoid a runtime error, I had to add a `field.Module` parameter, like this: `var getMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, typeof(TMember), new[] { typeof(TObject) }, field.Module, true);`

Answer (score 22):

[**2019 edit:** Since this post has always been one of my favorites, it is bittersweet to note that the approach I show here has been wholly superseded, in my own projects, by a newer, entirely different, and much sleeker technique, which I detail at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512720/147511)].

---

Using the new “[ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns)” feature in **C# 7.0** can make the process of creating and using runtime dynamically-generated get/set accessors much simpler and syntactically transparent. Instead of having to use [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?view=netframework-4.7) to emit separate **getter** and **setter** functions for accessing the field, you can now have a single method that returns a *managed pointer*-type reference to the field, es­sentially a single accessor that (in turn) enables convenient, ad-hoc *get* a̲n̲d̲ *set* access. Below, I provide a helper utility function which simplifies generating a *ByRef* getter function for any arbitrary (i.e. private) instance field in any class.

➜ ***For “just the code,” skip to note below.***

As a running example, let's say we want to access a private instance field `m_iPrivate`, an `int` defined in the class `OfInterestClass`:

```
public class OfInterestClass
{
    private int m_iPrivate;
};
```

Next let's assume we have a static field “reference-getter” function that takes a `OfInterestClass` instance and returns the desired field value ***by reference*** using the new **C# 7** “[ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns)” capability (below, I'll provide code to generate such functions at runtime, via [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod)):

```
public static ref int __refget_m_iPrivate(this OfInterestClass obj)
{
     /// ...
}
```

Such a function (“ref-getter,” let's say) is all we need in order to to have full read/write access to the private field. In the following examples, note especially the *setter*-invoking operation—and the de­monstrations of using the (i.e.) `++` and `+=` operators—since applying those operators directly to a *method call* may look a little unusual if you're not up-to-speed on **C#7**.

```
void MyFunction(OfInterestClass oic)
{
    int the_value = oic.__refget_m_iPrivate();      // 'get'
    oic.__refget_m_iPrivate() = the_value + 100;    // 'set'

    /// or simply...
    oic.__refget_m_iPrivate() += 100;                // <-- yes, you can

    oic.__refget_m_iPrivate()++;                     // <-- this too, no problem

    ref int prv = ref oic.__refget_m_iPrivate();     // via "ref-local" in C#7
    prv++;
    foo(ref prv);                                    // all of these directly affect…
    prv = 999;                                       // …field m_iPrivate 'in-situ'
}
```

As is the point, every operation shown in these examples manipulates `m_iPrivate` [*in situ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ) (i.e., *directly* within its containing instance `oic`) such that *any and all* changes are publicly visible there immediately. It's impor­tant to realize that this means that `prv`, despite being `int`-typed and locally declared, does not behave like your typical “local” variable. This is especially significant for concur­rent code; not only are changes visible *b̲e̲f̲o̲r̲e̲* `MyFunction` has exited, but now with **C# 7**, callers have the ability to *retain* a **ref return** managed pointer (as a [ref local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals)) and thus continue modifying the target for an arbitrarily long time *a̲f̲t̲e̲r̲wards* (albeit necessarily remaining *below* the ref-obtaining stack frame, that is).

Of course a main and obvious advantage of using a managed pointer here—and elsewhere in gen­eral—is that it continues to remain valid (again, within its stack frame's lifetime), even as `oic`—itself a reference-type instance allocated in the [GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection) heap—may be moved around during garbage collection. This is a gigantic difference versus na­tive pointers.

As sketched above, the ref-getter is a `static` [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that can be declared and/or used from anywhere. But if you're able to create your own class that's derived from `OfInterestClass` (that is, if `OfInterestClass` isn't [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed)), you can make this even nicer. In a derived class, you can expose C# syntax for using the base class's private field as if it were a public field of your derived class. To do this, just add a C# read-only ***ref return* property** to your class which binds the static ref-getter method to the current instance `this`:

```
public ref int m_iPrivate => ref __refget_m_iPrivate(this);
```

Here, the property is made `public` so anybody can access the field (via a reference to our derived class). We've essentially publicly published the private field from the base class. Now, in the derived class (or elsewhere, as appropriate) you can do any or all of the following:

```
int v = m_iPrivate;                             // get the value

m_iPrivate = 1234;                              // set the value

m_iPrivate++;                                   // increment it

ref int pi = ref m_iPrivate;                    // reference as C# 7 ref local

v = Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_iPrivate, 9999); // even do in-situ atomic operations on it!
```

As you can see, because the *property*, like the earlier *method*, also has a **by reference** return value, it behaves almost exactly like a field does.

So now for the details. How do you create the static **ref-getter** function that I showed above? Using `DynamicMethod`, this should be trivial. For example, here is the [IL](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) code for a traditional (by-value) static getter function:

```
// static int get_iPrivate(OfInterestClass oic) => oic.m_iPrivate;
IL_0000: ldarg.0    
IL_0001: ldfld Int32 m_iPrivate/OfInterestClass
IL_0006: ret
```

And here is the IL code that we want instead (ref-return):

```
// static ref int refget_iPrivate(OfInterestClass oic) => ref oic.m_iPrivate;
IL_0000: ldarg.0    
IL_0001: ldfld̲a Int32 m_iPrivate/OfInterestClass
IL_0006: ret
```

The only difference from the by-value getter is that we are using the `ldflda` (load field address) opcode instead of `ldfld` (load field). So if you're well-practiced with `DynamicMethod` it should be no problem, right?

> ***Wrong!***...
>      **unfortunately `DynamicMethod` does not allow a *by-ref* return value!**

If you try to call the `DynamicMethod` constructor specifying a `ByRef` type as the return value...

```
var dm = new DynamicMethod(
        "",                                 // method name
        typeof(int).MakeByRefType(),        // by-ref return type   <-- ERROR
        new[] { typeof(OfInterestClass) },  // argument type(s)
        typeof(OfInterestClass),            // owner type
        true);                              // private access
```

...the function throws `NotSupportedException` with the following message:

> The return Type contains some invalid type (i.e. null, ByRef)

Apparently, this function did not get the memo on C#7 and ref-return. Fortunately, I found a simple workaround that gets it working. If you pass a non-ref type into the constructor as a temporary "dummy," but then immediately afterwards use reflection on the newly-created `DynamicMethod` instance to change its `m_returnType` private field to be the **ByRef-type** type (*sic.*) that you actually want, then everything seems to work just fine.

To speed things up, I'll cut to the completed generic method which automates the whole process of by creating/returning a static ref-getter function for the private instance field of type `U`, having the supplied name, and defined in class `T`.

---

If you ***just want the complete working code***, copy from below this point to the end

---

First we have to define a delegate that represents the ref-getter, since a `Func<T,TResult>` delegate with ByRef usage can't be declared. Fortunately, the older `delegate` syntax does work for doing so (*phew!*).

```
public delegate ref U RefGetter<T, U>(T obj);
```

Place the delegate, along with the following static function in a centralized utility class where both can be accessed throughout your project. Here's the final ref-getter creation function which can be used to create a static ref-getter for the so-named instance field in any class.

```
public static RefGetter<T, U> create_refgetter<T, U>(String s_field)
{
    const BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Instance |
                            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    var fi = typeof(T).GetField(s_field, bf);
    if (fi == null)
        throw new MissingFieldException(typeof(T).Name, s_field);

    var s_name = "__refget_" + typeof(T).Name + "_fi_" + fi.Name;

    // workaround for using ref-return with DynamicMethod:
    //   a.) initialize with dummy return value
    var dm = new DynamicMethod(s_name, typeof(U), new[] { typeof(T) }, typeof(T), true);

    //   b.) replace with desired 'ByRef' return value
    dm.GetType().GetField("m_returnType", bf).SetValue(dm, typeof(U).MakeByRefType());

    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, fi);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (RefGetter<T, U>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefGetter<T, U>));
}
```

Returning now to outset of this article, we can easily provide the `__refget_m_iPrivate` function that got everything started. Instead of a static function written directly in C#, we will use the static ref-getter creation function to create the function body at runtime and store it in a static delegate-typed field (with the same signature). The syntax for calling it in the instance property (as shown above, and repeated below) or elsewhere is the same as if the compiler had been able to write the function.

Finally, to cache the dynamically-created ref-getter delegate, place the following line in any `static` class of your choice. Replace `OfInterestClass` with the type of the base class, `int` with the field type of the private field, and change the string argument to match the name of the private field. If you aren't able to create your own class derived from `OfInterestClass` (or don't want to), you're done; just make this field `public` and you can call it like a function, passing any `OfInterestClass` instance to get a reference which lets you read, write, or monitor its `int`-valued `private` field "`m_iPrivate`."

```
// Static delegate instance of ref-getter method, statically initialized.
// Requires an 'OfInterestClass' instance argument to be provided by caller.
static RefGetter<OfInterestClass, int> __refget_m_iPrivate = 
                                create_refgetter<OfInterestClass, int>("m_iPrivate");
```

Optionally, if you want to publish the hidden field with a cleaner or more natural syntax, you can define a (non-static) proxy class of your own which either *contains* an instance of—or perhaps even better (if possible), *derives from*—the field hiding class `OfInterestClass.` Instead of deploying the line of code previously shown globally in a `static` class, place it in your proxy class instead, and then also add the following line:

```
// optional: ref-getter as an instance property (no 'this' argument required)
public ref int m_iPrivate => ref __refget_m_iPrivate(this);
```

Comment: ...this...is....AMAZING!! I wish StackOverflow had a way to send people some of their points as a thank you lol. Genius hack around the ref return restriction in DynamicMethod...I would have definitely given up at that point. Did you report the shortcoming anywhere so it gets addressed?

Comment: @MikeMarynowski Thanks! Although [not ideal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192240), typically [people use bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144028) for that purpose.

Comment: I didn't realize I could put a bounty on another question that already had an answer and award it to any of the answers I wanted to. You got a +50 incoming in 23 hours for making my life SOOO much easier solving a problem with this.

Comment: Brilliant answer, this is what makes SO great! I was trying to get a pointer to a primitive field via reflection and this approach allowed me to do exactly that. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small fix for .NET 3.5 (for those of us using Unity and mono). DynamicMethod has no field "m_returnType" but it is called "returnType" instead. So I would refactor that to
`var f_returnType = dm.GetType().GetField("m_returnType", bf);
if (f_returnType == null) f_returnType = dm.GetType().GetField("returnType", bf);
f_returnType.SetValue(dm, typeof(U).MakeByRefType());`

Comment: @GlennSlayden Neat :) But is there a way to also do this in an Aot environment (like IL2CPP)? Is it possible to somehow "emulate" `Ldflda`? Maybe using something like `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`?

Comment: Are there any advantages to using `ref` when you only want read-only access a field that stores a reference-type?

Comment: @Dai No, not really. The IL for ref access will use superfluous indirection which would be unnecessary for simply grabbing a handle-valued field value, if you never need to alter that field value.

Comment: @GlennSlayden P.S. The reflection hack isn't needed on newer .NET Core runtimes. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30753

Answer (score 9):

No there is no easy way to create a delegate to get/set a field.

You will have to make your own code to provide that functionallity. I would suggest two functions in a shared library to provide this.

Using your code (in this example I only show the creation of the get-delegate):

```
static public class FieldInfoExtensions
{
    static public Func<S, T> CreateGetFieldDelegate<S, T>(this FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        var instExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S));
        var fieldExp = Expression.Field(instExp, fieldInfo);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<S, T>>(fieldExp, instExp).Compile();
    }
}
```

This makes it easy to create a get-delegate from a FieldInfo (assuming the field is of type int):

```
Func<MyClass, int> getter = typeof(MyClass).GetField("MyField").CreateGetFieldDelegate<MyClass, int>();
```

Or if we change your code a little bit:

```
static public class TypeExtensions
{
    static public Func<S, T> CreateGetFieldDelegate<S, T>(this Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        var instExp = Expression.Parameter(type);
        var fieldExp = Expression.Field(instExp, fieldName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<S, T>>(fieldExp, instExp).Compile();
    }
}
```

This makes it even more easy:

```
Func<MyClass, int> getter = typeof(MyClass).CreateGetFieldDelegate<MyClass, int>("MyField");
```

It is also possible to create these delegates using IL, but that code would be more complex and does not add much more performance, if any.

Comment: `No there is no easy way to create a delegate to get/set a field.` that answers my question, (already added by Ritchie). The rest is merely refactoring the code I already posted in the question to useful methods. Nevertheless thanks for chiming in. Btw, you can avoid `(Func<S,T>)` casts in your helper functions. nothing much, just readability

Comment: This worked well, but I ran some quick & dirty benchmarks and found that the compiled expression was be ever-so-slightly faster `~0.3-0.5ms` (faster) on the first run and when averaged across 10,000 executions was only `.8 µs` (micro) vs `1.1 µs` using `FieldInfo` directly... so virtually no difference.  And this requires a concrete Delegate to be known/defined... so if the flexibility of using FIeldInfo is needed then you aren't giving up much in terms of speed.

Answer (score 3):

`ref return` restriction in `DynamicMethod` seems to be gone **at least on v4.0.30319**.

Modified [this answer by Glenn Slayden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046664/4932128) with info [from microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods#to-define-and-execute-a-dynamic-method):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApp {
    public class MyClass {
        private int privateInt = 6;
    }

    internal static class Program {
        private delegate ref TReturn OneParameter<TReturn, in TParameter0>(TParameter0 p0);

        private static void Main() {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            var method = new DynamicMethod(
                "methodName",
                typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), // <- MakeByRefType() here
                new[] {typeof(MyClass)}, 
                typeof(MyClass), 
                true); // skip visibility


            const BindingFlags bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            var il = method.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, typeof(MyClass).GetField("privateInt", bindings));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            var getPrivateInt = (OneParameter<int, MyClass>) method.CreateDelegate(typeof(OneParameter<int, MyClass>));

            Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);
            Console.WriteLine(getPrivateInt(myClass));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
6
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware if you would use `Expression`, then why avoiding reflection? Most operations of `Expression` rely on reflection.

`GetValue` and `SetValue` themself are the `get method` and `set method`, for the fields, but they are not for any specific field.

Fields are not like properties, they are fields, and there's no reason to generate get/set methods for each one. However, the type may vary with different field, and thus `GetValue` and `SetValue` are defined the `parameter/return value` as `object` for variance. `GetValue` is even a abstract method, that is, for every class(still reflection) overriding it, must be within the identical signature.

If you don't *type* them, then the following code should do:

```
public static void SomeMethod(FieldInfo fieldInfo) {
    var Getter=(Func<object, object>)fieldInfo.GetValue;
    var Setter=(Action<object, object>)fieldInfo.SetValue;
}
```

but if you want, there's a constrained way:

```
public static void SomeMethod<S, T>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    where S: class
    where T: class {
    var Getter=(Func<S, object>)fieldInfo.GetValue;
    var Setter=(Action<S, T>)fieldInfo.SetValue;
}
```

For the reason that the `Getter` still be `Func<S, object>`, you might want to have a look of:

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Three: Method Group Conversion Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx) on Mr. Lippert's blog.

Comment: You: "then why avoiding reflection?" Answer: Yes, expressions also make use of reflection. Reflection is slow, so we have to avoid it. But you can use reflection and/or expressions to create a delegate. Once the delegate is created which DIRECTLY calls a method or DIRECTLY modifies a field, without using reflection, you have a very fast solution. So creating a delegate this way is slow, but calling it a million times is not.

Comment: @MartinMulder: Well, I believe there's no such delegate we can create for fields .. and maybe some workaround .. `OpCodes.Callvirt`

Comment: Depends how you look at it. A field is always written by a piece of code. So yes, a piece of code has to be present or has to be created. Once the piece of code is known, you can create a delegate to it. Creating this code (with Expressions) is rather slow, but once it is in place, it is fast.

Comment: @MartinMulder: As I mentioned in the answer, I cannot find more than `GetValue` and `SetValue`; but these methods are not binded to specific classes. So it doesn't depends on `how I ..`, it depends on how the language is implemented ..

Comment: `GetValue` and `SetValue` are both part of the reflection world. Creating a delegate to these function is fast. Calling them is still slow, because they are generic (for all kinds of fields). Calling them a million times is 1.000.000 x slow. And than I am not even talking about boxing and unboxing. If you create a piece of code with generic you actuall create functions LIKE `GetValue` and `SetValue`, but only specialized and high-speed. So in both cases your have a piece of code, but what piece of code would you prefer?

Comment: @MartinMulder: ... seems I'm not make myself clear, I'm saying AFAIK there's not something like that for fields .., however, I'm now trying to trace deeper in reflection to find.

Comment: @KenKin, this is a call to reflection each time. Though it technically answers my question, it was against the spirit of my question, ie performance :)

Comment: @nawfal: I know .. as the answers told, there are not something for fields as for properties naturely, you would need to write the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another option for creating a delegate when you are working with objects (don't know specific type of a field). Though it is slower if field is a structure (because of boxing).

```
public static class ReflectionUtility
{
    public static Func<object, object> CompileGetter(this FieldInfo field)
    {
        string methodName = field.ReflectedType.FullName + ".get_" + field.Name;
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, typeof(object), new[] { typeof(object) }, true);
        ILGenerator gen = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        if (field.IsStatic)
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, field);
            gen.Emit(field.FieldType.IsClass ? OpCodes.Castclass : OpCodes.Box, field.FieldType);
        }
        else
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, field.DeclaringType);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            gen.Emit(field.FieldType.IsClass ? OpCodes.Castclass : OpCodes.Box, field.FieldType);
        }
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Func<object, object>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, object>));
    }

    public static Action<object, object> CompileSetter(this FieldInfo field)
    {
        string methodName = field.ReflectedType.FullName + ".set_" + field.Name;
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod(methodName, null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }, true);
        ILGenerator gen = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        if (field.IsStatic)
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            gen.Emit(field.FieldType.IsClass ? OpCodes.Castclass : OpCodes.Unbox_Any, field.FieldType);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, field);
        }
        else
        {
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, field.DeclaringType);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            gen.Emit(field.FieldType.IsClass ? OpCodes.Castclass : OpCodes.Unbox_Any, field.FieldType);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        }
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<object, object>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, object>));
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as Zotta's answer, except non-generic?

Comment: Yeah, I modified Zotta's answer for case when you cannot use generics.

Comment: Trying to use the delegate that `CompileSetter` creates gives me the error *Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more ways of doing it :D

```cs
 public static Func<T, TResult> CreatePropertyOrFieldReaderDelegate<T, TResult>(string field)
        {
            var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(input, field), input).Compile();
        }
```

This will create a method that returns the value..

TEST CASE

```cs
class Testing {
  public int Data = 2;
  public string PropData { get; } = "Default";
 }


  [Fact]
  public void CreateSingleFieldReader()
        {
            var a = ReflectionHelper.CreatePropertyOrFieldReaderDelegate<Testing, int>("Data");
            Assert.Equal(2, a(new Testing()));

        }
```