# Get memory address of field using reflection (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .Net Core how do you get the memory address (IntPtr) of a primitive field when the parent object is not known at compile time?

If the object class was a struct and blittable then I could use Marshel.Offset, but unfortunately it is not.

The below code illustrates what I am trying to do

```
    class Example   // this class is defined in a different assembly and is not known at compile time
    {
        public double foo;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.foo = 123;

        var hdl = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr foo_add = GetAddressOf(obj, "foo");

        hdl.Free();
    }

    static IntPtr GetAddressOf(object pinned_object, string field_name)
    {
        FieldInfo field = pinned_object.GetType().GetField(field_name);
        return field.GetFieldAddress(pinned_object); // Unfortunatly this function does not exist, what are the alternatives?
    }
```

The alternative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994277/memory-address-of-an-object-in-c-sharp) looks at getting the memory address of an object, this can be done using GCHandle.Alloc and does not work for primitives.

Comment: Clearly *not* even close to a duplicate. Op asked about address of a primitive field. Other question is address of an object.

Answer (score 4):

The below answer describes how to obtain a managed referenced to a field using the "ref return" feature in C# 7.0:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046664/425678

Based on this brilliant answer we can modify the function `create_refgetter` to obtain an unmanaged pointer. This makes use of the little known function __makeref which is required when working with generic types ([detailed explanation](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/))

This function is then wrapped with the function `GetAddressOf` which allows calls without specifying the generic types.

```
    static IntPtr GetAddressOf(object pinned_object, string field_name)
    {
        var fi_val = pinned_object.GetType().GetField(field_name);
        var mi_all = typeof(Program).GetMethod("create_refgetter", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        var mi_generic = mi_all.MakeGenericMethod(pinned_object.GetType(), fi_val.FieldType);
        var ptr = (IntPtr) mi_generic.Invoke(null, new object[] {pinned_object, field_name });

        return ptr;
    }

    https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046664/425678

    public delegate ref U RefGetter<T, U>(T obj);
    public static IntPtr create_refgetter<T, U>(object obj,string s_field)
    {
        const BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.Instance |
                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

        var fi = typeof(T).GetField(s_field, bf);
        if (fi == null)
            throw new MissingFieldException(typeof(T).Name, s_field);

        var s_name = "__refget_" + typeof(T).Name + "_fi_" + fi.Name;

        // workaround for using ref-return with DynamicMethod:
        //   a.) initialize with dummy return value
        var dm = new DynamicMethod(s_name, typeof(U), new[] { typeof(T) }, typeof(T), true);

        //   b.) replace with desired 'ByRef' return value
        dm.GetType().GetField("m_returnType", bf).SetValue(dm, typeof(U).MakeByRefType());

        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, fi);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        RefGetter<T, U> ref_getter = (RefGetter<T, U>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefGetter<T, U>));

        unsafe
        {
            TypedReference t_ref = __makeref(ref_getter((T)obj));

            IntPtr ptr = *((IntPtr*)&t_ref);
            return ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Exmaple:

```
class Example   // this class is defined in a different assembly and is not known at compile time
{
    public double foo;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Example obj = new Example();
    obj.foo = 123;

    var hdl = GCHandle.Alloc(obj);

    unsafe
    {
        IntPtr foo_add = GetAddressOf(obj, "foo");

        double* ptr = (double*) foo_add;
        Console.WriteLine("Current Value: {0}", *ptr);

        *ptr = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("Updated Value: {0}", obj.foo);
    }

    hdl.Free();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Example Output:

```
Current Value: 123
Updated Value: 4
```